# android how to save give file names to saved files by coding

Tags: android, listview, download

i have some code that saves json files to internal or external memory, the problem i have is how to give them file names with coding so that when i users clicks on a listview item it assigns it a file name at runtime, i have no idea of where to start, i have code that saves a file eg

```
String filename = "storyOne.json"
```

i need this code to automaticly give it a file name with the .json extenton
can anyone help me of where to start???

the other problem is i have a listview of files that updates with what stories are avalible to download from a listview but dont know how to make it so that when the list gets bigger OnItemClick matches with how many stories there is here is my listview code

```
    @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


            if  (position == 0) { 
                showDialog(0);

            }

            if  (position == 1) { 

                showDialog(0);

            }

            if  (position == 2) { 
                showDialog(0);

            }

            if  (position == 3) { 
                showDialog(0);

            }
```

so with that code i can only save 4 files, how do i fix it so that it gives any new story an if statement.....
just so its clear i have a web site that users can submit stories, then android users can download those stories but i dont know how to make that work for when more stories are added
any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: good question but i carnt seem to get a response, anyone please help

Comment: can anyone that has viewed it let me nkow why no responses?

Comment: i dont get why no-one is commenting.....